# Пропуск точки остановки(breakpoint), отладчиком Microsoft visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, отладка

Все действия воспроизводятся с помощью visual studio 2015, выбран режим debug.
При попытке перейти к точке останова в нужной итерации в цикла, отладчик игнорирует эту точку и условие останова.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии клавищы F5 программа просто выполняется. 
Возможно я что то делаю не правильно. Как еще можно быстро перемещаться по итерациям цикла?

Comment: Попробуйте удалить все точки в проекте и поставить заново.

Comment: пробовал, не помогает. Без условия остановка происходит, но итерация нулевая, меня это не устраивает.

Comment: А, у вас еще и условная бряка... arrSize на начало цикла чему равен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил, точка останова должна находится внутри цикла, а не в строке его инициализации.

Comment: Думаю стоит добавить пояснение, что так потому , что в момент инициализации цикла hit count не может быть больше 5 ( на мой взгляд)

Comment: Да вы абсолютно правы, кроме того следует не забывать что он начинает счет от 1 а не от  0.

Comment: Проблема невнимательности при постановке контрольной точки - действительно та проблема которая должна быть отражена на форуме как полезный вопрос с полезным решением? В Borland c++ было видно какие шаги делает приложение, в vs нужно специально на бордюре кликать. По-моему логично - там где нужна остановка - там ставим. Ещё - в вопросе не видно тело цикла - значит вопрос был обречен остаться без ответа со стороны пользователей форума.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, да действительно проблема очень коварная и не очевидная, по этому о теле цикла я даже как то не думал.